# Output file not generated in Matlab after compiling

Tags: matlab, compilation, output, executable

I have the following code in my Matlab GUI file

```
    fileID = fopen('Game.txt','w');
    fileattrib('Game.txt','+w');
    fprintf(fileID,'%s %d ', 'You played level', handles.game_level);
    fprintf(fileID,'%s %d %s', 'and it took you', UserTries, 'tries');
    fileattrib('Game.txt','-w');
    fclose(fileID);
```

I use "deploytool" command to generate an executable using Matlab. But this procedure is not generating the Game.txt file when I execute the generated executable. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it does exists, but not where you expect it to be.
I guess you will find it on a directory where the ctf is extracted. The default it is somwhere below temp folder.
ctfroot() command will tell you exactly where it is.
To overcome this, create your file in some absolute path like c:\game.txt